# PHP Insert Command not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hi guys can you please tell me if there is an error on this code. this is not working. it didn't add any on my database. thanks you!

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mytable",$con);



if(isset($_POST['add'])){

// Variables

$acc_class = $_POST['acc_class'];

$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO mytable ('acc_class') VALUES ('$acc_class')";  

mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);

echo "Record Successfully Added!!";
};


mysql_close($con);

?>
<form action="add.php" method="post">

Account Classification:
<input  required="required" placeholder="e.g Hotel, Restaurant" type="text" name='acc_class' size=15 />

<input type="submit" name='add' Value='&nbsp;Add Record&nbsp;'/>
</form>
```

Comment: try some error checking.  mysql would be a good start. http://us1.php.net/mysql_error

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and is using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions which will be going away in a future version of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column name(s) should be wrapped in backticks and not quotes

```
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO mytable (`acc_class`) VALUES ('$acc_class')";
```

or remove the quotes

```
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO mytable (acc_class) VALUES ('$acc_class')";
```

I suggest you move to [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo).

and that you change `$acc_class = $_POST['acc_class'];` to

```
$acc_class = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acc_class']);
```

for the time being.

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

Comment: Hi Thank you i found the problem: mysql_select_db("mytable",$con); i input my table haha thanks anyway! i think i need to have a coffe and break. though your comment help me also after changing mt db. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I also suggest you move to `mysqli_*` with prepared statements or PDO. It's much better and safer, cheers @Nixxx27 However what's contained in my answer should be changed to that. You can't use quotes for column names (*and table names, should that happen in the future*).

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum:

```
$acc_class = $_POST['acc_class'];
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO mytable ('acc_class') VALUES ('$acc_class')";
```

Should be:

```
$acc_class = $_POST['acc_class'];
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO mytable ('acc_class') VALUES ('".$acc_class."')";
```

Also, it is unsafe to pass raw user input into to a SQL query in this way.  Please read up on SQL Injection.